# Python dictionary keys with matching values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this,

```
a= { 1:2, 3:4, 4:2, 8:3,7:4,9:3}
```

I want to find keys that have same values.
My output should be,

```
b=[ (1,4),(8,9),(3,7)]
```

How do I do that in a pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {1:2, 3:4, 4:2, 8:3,7:4,9:3, 5: 2}

valueDict = {}

mulKeys = []

for key, value in a.items():

    if valueDict.get(value) == None:

        valueDict[value] = [key]

    else:

        preExisting = valueDict[value]
        preExisting.append(key)
        valueDict[value] = preExisting




nested_lst_of_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in valueDict.values()]

print(nested_lst_of_tuples)
```

Note that, for your given question, the output YOU mentioned is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
a={ 1:2, 3:4, 4:2, 8:3,7:4,9:3} 
b=set(a.values())
l=[]
for i in b:
    l.append(tuple([k for k,v in a.items() if v == i]))

print l # [(1, 4), (8, 9), (3, 7)]
```

Distinct values in dictionary can be easily obtained using **set**.

**tuple()** converts the list into tuple.

Comment: He wants it as a list of tuples.

Comment: Thanks. Missed that out. I have made the changes.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.